# Extract/delete all other text than whats inside quotation marks (" "), and after string

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm have a very big data output in a .txt file that looks like this:

```
value1="1",value2="2",value3="test3",value4="4"
value1="1",value2="2",value3="anothertest3",value4="4"
value1="1",value2="2",value3="lasttest3",value4="4"
```

I want to extract the value within the quotation marks in value3, making the result look like this:

```
test3
anothertest3
lasttest3
```

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Search->Replace.
2. Set *Find what* to `^value1=".*",value2=".*",value3="(.{10})",value4=".*"$`.
3. Set *Replace with* to `\1`.
4. Set *Search Mode* to `Regular expression`.
5. Press *Replace All*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should've mentioned that all lines are different from eachother and contains different information in every variable. Also, they are not the same length or have the same amount of data.

Also, the value I want to extract from every line, contains 10 characters. Is it possible to make it show the 10 chars after a certain text?

Comment: I've edited my answer to allow different values for value1, value2 and value4, and it now assumes value3 will be 10 characters long.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to just show the 10 characters that follow `value3="`. To do so, use `.*value3="(.{10})`. The disadvantage of this is it doesn't account for the context since it's not actually parsing the data. For example, if a line was `value1=",value3=",value121="",value3="anothertes"`, the expression would probably yield `,value121=` instead of `anothertes`.

Answer (score 2):

With Search Mode=`Regular Expression`

Search for: `^.*,value3="([^"]*)".*$`
Replace with: `\1`

Answer (score 1):

Sam's solution didn't work for me.

For the example data you provided, the following regex worked. It doesn't have any assumptions on length, other than that the value cannot contain a `"`, even if it's escaped (depending on your data's source, this was worth mentioning).

This also doesn't assume there is a `value1` or `value2` preceding it. They can be optionally omitted, or there can optionally be additional or otherwise unordered values.

1. Search -> Replace (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>)
2. Set search mode to *Regular Expression*
3. Enter the following for the *Find what* field

   ```
   ^.*value3="([^"]*)".*$
   ```
4. Set *Replace with* to `$1`
5. *Replace all*